# Error updating database (code just crashes)

Tags: php, mysqli

Im trying to make a shop mechanism for a game but the action code is doing nothing as soon as i enter the UPDATE statement into it.

Can anyone see whats the problem? Might be a really dumb one.

Code below:

```
<?php 
include('include/configdb.php');
$user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];
$safegun = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['gun']);
if($safegun == 0){
echo 'Please specify an amount';
} elseif($safegun >= 1){
//Db thingy`s
$mysqli->query("UPDATE user SET money= ".$safegun." * 300 gun = gun+"$safegun" WHERE username = '".$user_name."'");
sleep(30);
header('location:shop.php');
}
```

Any help will be much apreceated.
Kind Regards,
Michael

Comment: Why are you sleeping for 30 seconds on the server causing a connection to be open and a thread to be used?

Comment: That was just a test but that even did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your UPDATE syntax is wrong, if you are going to update more than one column, you should separate them with a comma. So it should be:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE user SET money= ".$safegun." * 300, gun = gun+"$safegun" WHERE username = '".$user_name."'");
```

Reference: [Manual](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)

Note that I don't know how you declared `$mysqli` connection. If you used a 3-parameters-only constructor (see docs: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) you should add `db_name` in you MySQL commands:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE db_name.user SET money= ".$safegun." * 300, gun = gun+"$safegun" WHERE username = '".$user_name."'");
```

Comment: Thanks man but it doesnt seem to work and sins i cant alter my .htacces and dont have acces to php.ini i cant turn error reporting on

Comment: @Trojan_DC wait...where did you open a new $mysqli instance?

Comment: In my configdb file its the main bi

Comment: If you are you sure the code enters correctly the IF statement, then are you sure as well that while opening the connection you selected the database that contains the table called user?

Comment: Yes i use $mysqli throughout the entire site and it never failed until here

Comment: @Trojan_DC if it's really echoing 1 (true), it means the query succeded

Answer (score 0):

Please see this:
[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

It  says that it excepts 1 string. not 2, remove it from your:

`$safegun = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['gun']);`
To:
`$safegun = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['gun']);`

and:

`$mysqli->query("UPDATE user SET money= ".$safegun." * 300 gun = gun+"$safegun" WHERE username = '".$user_name."'");`

To:

`$mysqli->query("UPDATE user SET money= '$safegun' * 300, gun = gun+'$safegun' WHERE username = '$user_name' ");`
Edited.

Comment: That fix gives me the exact same error: A blank page

Comment: Edited..
Check again.

Comment: Ok that fixed the crash but it stil doesnt alter the db

Comment: echo your query. then you know what is wrong...
and makesure you have everything connected.
also, mark this as the right answer as it answered your question and fixed your bugs.

Comment: Gives me a 1 when i echo it